# Why Can't I set Y-AXES min and max values

Tags: c#, charts

I am trying to set the min and max of the two Y-Axes on a chart and all I am getting is 0 to 100 for both.

I have included both my init code and the chart filling code.

I am obviously not asking the question the right way or I would have found an answer by now.

Am I missing a "Using" Statement?

Thanks Guys

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

    public void initChart()
    {
        //Set up empty Chart area
        chart1.ChartAreas.Add("area");
        chart1.ChartAreas["area"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

        chart1.Series.Add("Heart Rate");
        chart1.Series["Heart Rate"].Color = Color.Red;
        chart1.Series["Heart Rate"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;

        chart1.Series.Add("SPo2");
        chart1.Series["SPo2"].Color = Color.Blue;
        chart1.Series["SPo2"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
    }

    public void plotHR()
    {
        double hrValue;
        double o2Value;
        string xStr;
        try
        {
            chart1.Series["Heart Rate"].Points.Clear();
        }
        catch
        {
            // do nothing
        }

        try
        {
            chart1.Series["SPo2"].Points.Clear();
        }
        catch
        {
            // do nothing
        }
        chart1.Series["SPo2"].YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
        chart1.Series["Heart Rate"].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
        for (int rPtr = 0; rPtr < dgvWorking.RowCount - 1; rPtr ++)
        {
            hrValue = Convert.ToDouble(dgvWorking.Rows[rPtr].Cells[3].Value);
            o2Value = Convert.ToDouble(dgvWorking.Rows[rPtr].Cells[2].Value);
            string strTemp = dgvWorking.Rows[rPtr].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + " " + dgvWorking.Rows[rPtr].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            xStr = strTemp.Replace(":", "");

            chart1.Series["Heart Rate"].Points.AddXY(strTemp, hrValue);
            chart1.Series["SPo2"].Points.AddXY(strTemp, o2Value);
        }

        //chart1.ChartAreas["area"].RecalculateAxesScale();

        //chart1.Series["Heart Rate"].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
        chart1.ChartAreas["area"].AxisY.Interval = 5.00;
        chart1.ChartAreas["area"].AxisY.Minimum = 40.00;
        chart1.ChartAreas["area"].AxisY.Maximum = 90.00;

        //chart1.Series["SPo2"].YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
        chart1.ChartAreas["area"].AxisY2.Interval = 5.00;
        chart1.ChartAreas["area"].AxisY2.Minimum = 60.00;
        chart1.ChartAreas["area"].AxisY2.Maximum = 100.00;


    }
```

Comment: _chart1.Series["SPo2"].Points.AddXY(strTemp, o2Value);_ Adding x-values as string sets them all to 0 and prevent use of any formatting, scaling etc, including minimum/maximum etc. You need to add them as numbers (or possibly as DateTimes) !! (Note that those string do show up in the labels, but the x-values are all 0, i.e. useless!

Comment: It is the Y-Axes I am having trouble with.

Comment: Whoops. Well, the code works fine here. Can you show a picture?

Comment: You are adding a ChartArea `area` but I see no code to associate your series with it, like so: `chart1.Series["SPo2"].ChartArea = chart1.ChartAreas["area"].Name`. Did you clear the default ChartArea? If nor the series will appear there and those axes are in a ca with neither series nor data..

Comment: TaW Thanks! That seems to have fixed the issue.

Now I am displaying Heart Rate 40-90 on the left and Oxygenation 60-100 on the right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Chart` control added from the designer has a default `ChartArea` and a `Series` and a `Legend`, all associated.

If you have more than one `ChartArea`, e.g. because you created one without clearing the default one with `chart.ChartAreas.Clear()`, any `Series` you add will still be associated with the 1st `ChartArea`.

To associate a `Series s` with a `ChartArea ca` you write:

```
s.ChartArea = ca.Name;
```

or with your names:

```
chart1.Series["SPo2"].ChartArea = chart1.ChartAreas["area"].Name
```

Since you explictly turned on the axes of the new `ChartArea` but still used the `Series` associated with the default `ChartArea` the new axes values didn't show..

Note that a `Chart` control created in code `Chart chart = new Chart();` will be all empty and you need to add its 1st `ChartArea` etc..

Answer (score 0):

This could be the reason: [Axis.Minimum Property (Remarks)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.minimum(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1)

> Note that if you set this value explicitly, the X-values of data elements must be taken into account. If all data points have X-values of zero, the Chart control will assume the first data point occurs at zero. Also, if the Minimum value is explicitly set, the IsStartedFromZero property will be ignored. The Minimum value must be less than the Maximum value.